# Control (power on/off, monitor) a desktop PC with ESP8266?

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, esp8266

I'm trying to

1. power on, power off my desktop PC
2. monitor my desktop PC

by connecting ESP8266 with the mainboard's F_PANEL.

This is what I know:

- You can power on the mainboard by connecting PW- and PW+ (in the F_PANEL) for a brief time
- ESP8266 will fry if connected with a 5v external source

This is what I imagined:

[image: breadboard]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftvr9i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Power on/off: Send a signal from GPIO13 to a transistor that will connect PW+ with PW-
- Monitor: Read a signal from voltage divided PWR to GPIO14

Would the above idea work? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

PC Power switch is a logic switch to Gnd with standby +5V R_pullup on the switch. It is a toggle function so just momentary using NPN open collector to 0V.  The base drive current is amplified so only needs< 0.1mA so +5Vstdby can provide this. 9V is redundant.

Comment: You mean I can remove the 9V and wire `PW+` with `Vin` to power the microcontroller (ESP8266)?

Comment: Yes . just simulate a switch to gnd. with a transistor ( open collector) measure V =5V.

Comment: If power + is the 5V STB always on power source from the power supply, yes.

Comment: `PW+` is always on, but it must be connected with `PW-` momentary to turn on the computer. During that time, would ESP8266 have enough power to operate?

Comment: You get pwr from +5Vstb then only apply a pulsed logic “0” open collector to PS_On signal